# Read input continuously in bash

Tags: bash

I have a simple question. I know that shell scripts are slow/ineffective when it comes to recursion and looping.

Generally, is it possible to read the input continuously instead of having to loop the read/"grab" part of the code, for instances when the input is continual and in plenty( a kind of EVENT DRIVEN scenario ).

For example,,
I use fedora16(gnome3.2) and for reasons unknown the capslock notification is missing. I own a netbook and don't have the "luxury" of indicator leds. So I've decided to write a shell script to notify me when the capslock key is pressed. I figured out a way to know the key state.

```
xset -q | grep Caps | awk '{print $4}'
```

that would give me "on"/"off" as the output. I can like have the loop to execute every one second(or less) but that would be a very crude way of doing it.

Comment: It doesn't solve your bash problem but maybe you want to use something like this: [lock-keys-applet](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/lock-keys-applet]) or [indicator-keylock](https://launchpad.net/~tsbarnes/+archive/indicator-keylock)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is event-driven. `xset -q` produces some output, which only at that point (i.e. when it's produced) is consumed by `grep`. At that point, `grep` might produce some output (only if it matches Caps) and only in that case will `awk` process something.

The problem here is not bash - the "problem" is `xset -q`. It was not designed to continuously give you output. It was designed as a one-shot output command.

To touch the other part of the question - if you actually just need an indicator, look here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available/37998#37998

An excellent source of all sorts of indicators. One of them is Keylock indicator (search the above page to see more info):

[image: Keylock indicator]

The above link is from askubuntu.com, i.e. it's Ubuntu-centric, but the above seems to be available for Fedora, too:

- http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=257835

From the above thread ([this post](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showpost.php?s=a94017b337b2936485ceb050e1e4bb8a&p=1437063&postcount=3) by fewt):

```
su -
yum install lock-keys-applet
exit
killall -HUP gnome-panel
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have Ubuntu on my other partiton. I have used indicator-keylock before :) ( infact when I first started writing the script I had this app in my mind ). Lock keys applet isn't there on the official repos anymore.(was it there in the first place?) . I have figured out a way. I guess i will bind the capslock key to run the script every time it is pressed. that would be much easier :) But I have no idea how to do that! The built in keyboard shortcuts app will accept only multiple key combinations. :(